# SQL Server 2008 - Cannot insert due to 'conflict with the FK constraint'

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, conflict, insert-into

My query is given below:

```
insert into Orders
values
('20012', /*order num, pk*/
'6-10-2012', /*date, i wrote it in a different format, is that okay ?*/
'1000000012'/*customer id, fk*/
)
```

The error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint  
"FK_Orders_Customers".   
The conflict occurred in database "MyDB", table "dbo.Customers", column 'cust_id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Why do i get this error ? How can i insert some dummy values into this table ?

Comment: are you sure 1000000012 exists and that it's TEXT?

Comment: @xQbert - I presume you mean a string rather than `TEXT` (that is the name of a deprecated large object datatype). Though the quotes aren't needed / shouldn't be there if the column is in fact numeric SQL Server will implicitly convert `1000000012` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the error because there is no record in the "Customers" table with the customer id 1000000012 in the "cust_id" column. Insert that record into the "Customers" table first and you should be fine.

Comment: got it. So, the db checks if the customer exists or not before you can insert something into the orders table. Can you tell me how that is accomplished ? I am new and trying to take a crash course in SQL.

Comment: Basically a foreign key is a column in one table that references a column in another table. So the data you insert into a column marked as a foreign key must exist in the column that is being reference. You will probably bump into it later also on deletes. Say you wanted to delete that customer later, you will not be able to do it while that customer is being referenced by the order that you are trying to insert now. Anyway, the important point here is that the customer must exist in the DB before you can insert an order for that particular Customer.

Comment: SQL server takes care of all of the checking these things, to create a foreign key it is done at the time the table is created. This would have been included in the create table statement for the Orders table you are using: FOREIGN KEY (Cust_id) REFERENCES Customers(Cust_id). Have a look here if you want to learn more about it: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, it sounds like you do not have a customer record with id '1000000012' in your customers table

Comment: yes. I now used a customer id that exists. The insert was successful. So, the db checks if the customer exists or not before you can insert something into the orders table. Can you tell me how that is accomplished ? I am new and trying to take a crash course in SQL.

Comment: There is a foreign key to the customers defined on the customer id field in your orders table. This means that the database insists that any id you enter in that field has a corresponding id in the customer table. Look up foreign keys in books online for more info.